Broken screen, need to recover data
my Pixel 4a Screen just went black for whatever reason. Developer mode is not enabled, so no adb possible...
I can unlock the device using a keyboard. Does anyone know of a way I can get my data without replacing the screen?
I can install apps via the play store website from my pc, so technically i can install a screen share or backup app, but I would need a guide that gets me step by step through the app setup once installed.
Easiest way would be to change the USB-Connection to MTP but I didn't find a way to connect my phone to the PC & a keyboard at the same time - any ideas?
Bonus question: How can i get to the app drawer and search + open a specific app with just the attached keyboard?
Thanks!

Related: Enable ADB .. Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen Found (but not tested): https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyA50/comments/zz4cw2/help_with_getting_talkback_turned_on_no_screen/ You probably should mention what you think the OS version is as screen shots may be of assistance
